# Remove or unload loaded XML using XDocument from memory

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I have started the console application and it has taken 100MB of RAM. 
After executing below statement, RAM is increased to 115MB.
`XDocument xdocument = XDocument.Load("temp.xml")` 
It will load XML in memory. 
Now I want my application to go down to near 100 MB. 
What if I have to recover 15 MB of increased RAM. I can not see any functions in XDocument for this. I want to remove/unload above XML from memory.xdocument = null will not solve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collection should take care of that, if not, there´s most likely an object holding a reference to your xdocument object keeping it from being disposed. Maybe you can use a third party tool like Ants Memory Profiler to see what object it is, keeping your xml document from beaing released from memory.